# Android foreground service for music player

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have developed a music player app that uses a foreground service and have used Remote views within a notification for displaying controls(play/pause, next, previous). When a user taps the notification, how could I make appropriate changes to the controls displayed in the Activity like the seek bar progress and other UI updates with respect to the current song.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try with below open source project , you will get help from these projects

1. [UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer)
2. [JamsMusicPlayer](https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer)
3. [TurtlePlayer](https://github.com/eddturtle/TurtlePlayer)